# Should I use "awe of" or "awe at"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, writing-style

The full sentence is:

> I express unqualified **awe at** Nathaniel.

Comment: How about `Ave caesar`?

Comment: The only question is in the title, and there is no explanation or clarification  as to why you are/were confused. Such a drastic edit as yours is disrespectful to the users who answered your post. "Less", in this case is not "more" but instead, "poor"!

Answer (score 1):

*[Be/stand **in awe of** somebody/something](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/awe_1)* is an idiomatic expression whose meaning is quite close to the concept you want to express. The fixed phrase is ***in awe of***:

> - to admire someone or something and be slightly frightened of them/it
>
>   - *While Diana was in awe of her grandfather, she adored her grandmother.*

(Oxford Learner's Dictionary)

The preposition **at**, used with **in awe** can be found in sentences like the following where it refers to the preceding verb or expression:

> - they gazed in awe at the president.
> - I simply looked on in awe at the remains of what I had just enjoyed.

([The Oxford dictionary of difficult words](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA40&dq=%22in%20awe%20at%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIwK7Rss_tyAIVyX4aCh2kIwb7#v=onepage&q=%22in%20awe%20at%22&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

This ngram shows the usage in published works from Google Books.

[Google ngram:awe of,awe at,in awe of,in awe at](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=awe+of%2Cawe+at%2Cin+awe+of%2Cin+awe+at&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cawe%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cawe%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20awe%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20awe%20at%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

You can click on the links at the bottom of that page to see the actual texts--notice that punctuation is ignored in the search results.

In your context I prefer:  "My main purpose is to express, from afar, unqualified awe ***of*** my leader, Nathaniel."

I don't think you can express awe ***at*** someone like some kind of fluid. (apologies for the possible mental image)